# PHP : Encoding nested JSON array issue

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am confused writing this one, how can i achieve achieve this similar output. I'm doing json encode since early. But this one is different for me.

```
 [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        innerSize: '40%',
        data: [
            ['Firefox',   10.38],
            ['IE',       56.33],
            ['Chrome', 24.03],
            ['Safari',    4.77],
            ['Opera',     0.91],
            {//over here i can't get this braces
                name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                y: 0.2,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
```

Here is my code,

```
$percentage = array();
$arr2 = new stdClass();
$arr2->type = 'pie';
$arr2->name = 'Browser share';
$arr2->innerSize = '40%';
while($azSoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($az)){ 
    $arr2->data[] = array("".$azSoc['criteria_name']."", $azSoc['crit_score_percentage']);
}
$arr2->name = 'Porperty ok';
$arr2->y = 0.2;
$arr2->dataLabels[] = array('enable',false);
array_push($percentage, $arr2);
echo json_encode( $percentage);
```

The output of my codes gives me,

```
[{"type":"pie","name":"Porperty ok","innerSize":"40%","data":[["tes","25"],
["awdawdas","25"],["awdawd","25"],["ehhehe","25"]],"y":0.2,"dataLabels":
[["enable",false]]}]
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not valid JSON.

Comment: But how, maybe I am wrong with my question is it an array? Because I already did it on my other code several times. Putting in js and rewrite by json.parse works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not valid json. You need to create a new occurance in your array with a name `some_name` and then load the object into that occurance

```
$percentage = array();

$arr2 = new stdClass();
$arr2->type = 'pie';
$arr2->name = 'Browser share';
$arr2->innerSize = '40%';
while($azSoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($az)){ 
    $arr2->data[] = array("".$azSoc['criteria_name']."", $azSoc['crit_score_percentage']);
}

$t = new stdClass();
$t->name = 'Porperty ok';
$t->y = 0.2;
$t->dataLabels = array('enable',false);
$arr2->data['some_name'] = $t;

$percentage[] = $arr2;

//dont know where $cat came from I assume its a larger oject you are building
echo json_encode( $cat);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `array('enable',false);` It should be `array('enable' => false);`